# Session of Node API working in postman well but not in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating a node API for authentication, in my node API I have created a login session and storing it. Now the problem is that it's working in postman well, but in the browser, it's not working. I am assuming its a problem with cookies setting, being new in node please give me a proper suggestion for this issue. I have given the codes.

In app.js set the express-session in this way.

```
app.use(session({ secret: 'middesecrectcode', resave:false, saveUninitialized:true }))
```

In my API routes, I have done that.

```
 router.post('/testlogin', function(req, res, next){  
    req.session.username = "midde";
    res.send("Your session has been created as "+ req.session.username); 
    req.session.success = true;
});


router.get('/checkSession', function(req, res, next){
   console.log(req.session.success); 
   if(req.session.username){
    res.send("hello "+req.session.username);  
   } 
   else{
       res.send("session is not SET");
   }
});

router.get('/logout', function(req, res, next){
    req.session.destroy(function(err){
       if(err){
           console.log("Some error received when to logout");
       }
       res.send("You have got logged out successfully");
    });
});
```

And in the browser i am calling the API in the following way

**login.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="login.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div>
        <label><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" id="uname">
        </br>
        <label><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" id="pwd">
        </br>

        <button id="btn" type="submit">Login</button>
      </div>

      <div>
          <button id="btnSession" type="submit">Check Session</button>
      </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**login.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        var uname = $("#uname").val();
        var pwd = $("#pwd").val();

        var dataSet = {
            "username" : uname,
            "password": pwd
            } 
        var data2send = JSON.stringify(dataSet) 
         console.log(data2send);

       $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/api/testLogin",
                type: "post",
                data: data2send,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(d) {
                    alert(d);
                }
            });

    });

    $("#btnSession").click(function(){   
       $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/api/checkSession",
                type: "get",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(d) {
                    alert(d);
                }
            });

    });

});
```

Comment: have u tried using the code generated by postman in your browser? https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets

Comment: Are you getting an error response? Be more specific than "It's not working"

Comment: @Baksteen ,  No i am not getting any error, when calling 'testlogin' API, getting the response that "Your session has been created as midde", Now when checking the session, it responses that "session is not SET".

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the fact that you're calling `res.send` before `req.session.success = true;`.

Make sure you've done all your stuff before sending a response. Try swapping those lines like this:

```
router.post('/testlogin', function(req, res, next){  
    req.session.username = "midde";        
    req.session.success = true;
    res.send("Your session has been created as "+ req.session.username); 
});
```

Comment: Same problem with this change, working on postman successfully (Session getting stored) but not in browser.

Comment: are you sure you're doing a POST request in your browser?

Comment: when I am calling "testlogin", then doing POST request and when just checking session then doing GET request as per the API created, Can you please tell me should I need to store the cookies on browser or not with it ?? I think I am making some silly mistake, but cant find it.